# Cannot find function src_dbi in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to access postgresql db on Heroku, and I found that I can use src_dbi from dplyr package.

I have dplyr properly installed, but when I try to call src_dbi I get an error message:

```
Error in src_dbi(db_con) : could not find function "src_dbi"
```

This happens right when I run:

```
db <- src_dbi(db_con)
```

after poviding the credentials:

```
config <- run("heroku", c("config:get", "postgres://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
", "-a", "prjectAlpha"))
pg <- httr::parse_url(config$stdout)
dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
          dbname = "xxxxxxxxxx",
          host = "xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com",
          port = 5432,
          user = "xxxxxx",
          password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          sslmode = "require"
) -> db_con
```

The idea is to be able to download a table and re-upload it after making a few changes with R.

Comment: I believe `src_dbi()` is in `dbplyr` not `dplyr`

Comment: I just tried with dbplyr and get:
> system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")
> install.packages("dbplyr")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.5/dbplyr_1.4.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 565309 bytes (552 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 552 KB

tar: Failed to set default locale

The downloaded binary packages are in
 /var/folders/c_/cqbnlqbx5lq7vjgf31_wsgvh0000gp/T//Rtmpqcfe3h/downloaded_packages

Comment: I believe you need to restart R after you run the `system()` command before you install the package.

Comment: Just did, same error:

Comment: Then you have me stumped at this point. I apologize I couldn’t be of more help.

Comment: All good, got connected, can start working now. Thank you !!!!

Comment: Will, sorry last question, once the connection is established,  I run db <- src_dbi(db_con), then I can see all the tables online by calling db. Do you know How I can download one of the table to a dataframe locally please ?

Comment: that would best be asked under a new question, that way other users looking for the answer will be able to find it.

Comment: All good, i put below the full solution as I used it, and it worked well. Thank you for  helping earlier

Answer (score 0):

My solution to access Heroku Postgresql from R:

```
library(dbplyr) #in case you have an error, run: system("defaults write org.R-project.R force.LANG en_US.UTF-8")  from Rails console, then restart R.
library(processx)
library(RPostgres)
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

config <- run("heroku", c("config:get", "postgres://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
", "-a", "prjectAlpha"))
pg <- httr::parse_url(config$stdout)
dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
          dbname = "xxxxxxxxxx",
          host = "xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com",
          port = 5432,
          user = "xxxxxx",
          password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          sslmode = "require"
) -> db_con
```

#### Once the connection is set up:

```
db <- src_dbi(db_con)
```

#### Once the connection is established, check for the available tables

```
db
```

#### Now time to retrive data

A lot of examples only show treatment directly from the collection, but one might just be interested to read the tables. I have a table called "weather_records"

```
weather_records_local_df <- tbl(db_con, "weather_records")
df <- collect(weather_records_local_df)
```

Then do what you want with the data. Hope it helps.